# Should participles apparently used as substantivized adjectives be capitalized after "etwas + prepositional phrase"?

Tags: spelling

I'm working with a text in which substantivized adjectives after "etwas" are capitalized, just as you would expect, for example "etwas Neues".  However, I have just encountered the following phrase: "X ist etwas ganz außerhalb der Kirche stehendes."  Should "stehendes" be capitalized, just as "Neues" is?  It seems to have the same substantivized adjectival function, even though it is used in tandem with a prepositional phrase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is in the word class. *Neu* is an adjective, and *Neues* is a noun made from an adjective. That's why it is capitalized.

In contrary, *stehen**d**es* is **not** an adjective but a present participle of the verb *stehen*. You can tell from the embedded **d**. These participles are often used to replace a relative clause, they aren't turned into nouns then.

> Es ist etwas, das ganz außerhalb der Kirche steht.
>
> Es ist etwas ganz außerhalb der Kirche stehendes.

A true adjective had to use the verb **sein** in a relative clause and the replacement:

> Es ist etwas, das ganz neu **ist**.
>
> Es ist etwas ganz neu **seiendes**.

That sounds awkward, and that's the reason a noun is preferred.

> Es ist etwas ganz Neues.

---

You can of course also turn the present participle into a noun, but that noun means the action as a concept.

> Das Bewegende überholt das Stehende.
>
> Das Nicht-Seiende überwiegt das Seiende.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives and adverbs (like other word classes) can form substantized expressions, and can thus carry articles and prepositional phrases.

Capitalization is very generally:

If there is a noun clause that the substantized adjective refers to, you write lower case. If not, upper case.

> Das ist was Neues: Menschen benutzen keine Smartphones mehr.

here "Neues" is upper-cased, as there is no substantive it refers to, vs.

> Wir haben zwei Männer getroffen: Der jüngere war mir sehr sympathisch.

"der jüngere" clearly refers to one of the "Männer" in the previous sentence, and thus appears in lower case.

Comment: Actually, in this context, you "Capitalize", you don't  "write UPPER CASE".

Comment: Excellent point to refer to substantivized adjectives rather than simply adjectives. I have edited the original question accordingly.